# I want to send the outputs of python to the database

Tags: python, postgresql, opc-ua

I am trying to send the outputs I got in python to the database. Like I am reading valves from my plc using the OPC UA server via python. I can read my variables every second, Now I want to send those values to my PostgreSQL database. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much again.

I created a connection between python and PostgreSQL by using the psycopg module. And I am able to create the tables using my python script.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your python script. Also, post what you have tried so far and what kind of data you want to 'send' to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having to script directly with `psycopg`, I usually reccomend using [SqlAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html), which is a nice wrapper for psycopg that makes editing data in the database much easier

Eg, by using the same `psycopg` engine you have already set up, you can do:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(engine) as session:

     spongebob = User(
         name="spongebob",
         fullname="Spongebob Squarepants",
         addresses=[Address(email_address="spongebob@sqlalchemy.org")],
     )
     sandy = User(
         name="sandy",
         fullname="Sandy Cheeks",
         addresses=[
             Address(email_address="sandy@sqlalchemy.org"),
             Address(email_address="sandy@squirrelpower.org"),
         ],
     )
     patrick = User(name="patrick", fullname="Patrick Star")

     session.add_all([spongebob, sandy, patrick])

     session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a connection between python and postgreSQL database by using

```
psycopg2.connect(dbname="dbname", port= 6543, user="postgres", password="password", host="host.docker.internal")
```

I give host details for creating docker image and use it.